# Multiple queries on feature layer ArcGIS JS API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am developing a web application (with ArcGIS Javascript 4.15) where I can click on a property. From the geometry of the property, I am querying feature layers that are listed in an object and have using [this topic](https://developers.arcgis.com/labs/javascript/query-a-feature-layer/) to get some inpiration. I want to have the result to be added in a popup, but this one keeps being empty at the end of the process.The thing is that my console shows the data I want to get, but It's happening after the main function has returned something. I know my issue is related to asynchronous function. But somehow I can't make my code working. Here is my code:

```
require([
    "esri/Map",
    "esri/views/MapView",
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
    "esri/widgets/BasemapToggle",
    "esri/widgets/BasemapGallery",
    "esri/widgets/Expand",
    "esri/widgets/Search",
    "esri/widgets/DistanceMeasurement2D",
    "esri/widgets/AreaMeasurement2D",
    "esri/geometry/geometryEngine",
    "esri/Graphic",
    "esri/geometry/Polygon",
    "esri/tasks/Locator",
], function(Map, MapView, FeatureLayer,BasemapToggle, BasemapGallery,Expand,Search,DistanceMeasurement2D, AreaMeasurement2D,geometryEngine,Graphic,Polygon,Locator) {


  const overlays={"land_use":"https://gisservices4.information.qld.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/QldGlobe/Planning/MapServer/165",
  "planning_boundary":"https://gisservices4.information.qld.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/QldGlobe/Planning/MapServer/10"
  }

    //renderer/symbology LGA
    const renderer_data = {
      type: "simple",  // autocasts as new SimpleRenderer()
      symbol: {
        type: "simple-fill",  // autocasts as new SimpleFillSymbol()
        color: [ 255, 128, 0, 0 ],
        outline: {  // autocasts as new SimpleLineSymbol()
          width: 1.5,
          color: "orange"
        }
      }
    };
    //property layer
    const lyr_address= new FeatureLayer({
        url:"https://gisservices4.information.qld.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/QldGlobe/CadastralFramework/MapServer/5",
        renderer:renderer_data,
        popupTemplate: {dockOptions: {
          // Disables the dock button from the popup
          buttonEnabled: true,
          // Ignore the default sizes that trigger responsive docking
          breakpoint: true,
          position:"top-right"
        },
          title: "Report",
          content: query_prop,
        },
        outFields: ["*"],
      });

    //create the map environment
    const map = new Map({
    basemap: "topo-vector",
    layers:[lyr_address], 
    });
    //create the viewer
    const view = new MapView({
    container: "viewDiv",
    map: map,
    center: [153.13,-27.63],
    scale:3000,
    popup: {
      dockEnabled: true,
      dockOptions: {
        // Disables the dock button from the popup
        buttonEnabled: true,
        // Ignore the default sizes that trigger responsive docking
        breakpoint: false,
        position: "top-right"
      }}
    // scale:
    });

 //------------------------------------------------
  //* to query the data when we click on the map
    function query_prop(target){
      const geom_extract=target.graphic.geometry;
      const content_import=query_data(geom_extract);
      return content_import;
    }
 

 async function query_data(geom_extract){
  const dicotest={}
  // to review element of the dict
    Object.keys(overlays).map(function(key, index) {
      // get Mapservice url
     const ms_url=overlays[key]
    //  query the layer
     const flyr_query= new FeatureLayer({
      url:ms_url
    });
    // get the query feature attribute
    return flyr_query.queryFeatures( { geometry: geom_extract,
      spatialRelationship: "intersects",
      outFields: ["*"],
      returnGeometry: true,
      }).then(function(result) {
      const feats=result.features;
      if(feats.length==0){
          dicotest[key]= "NA"
          }
      else{
       const input_attribute=[]
          feats.map(function(feature){
            input_attribute.push(feature.attributes)
      })
      dicotest[key]=input_attribute
      console.log(dicotest)
      return JSON.stringify(dicotest)
        }
      })
})
    }
})
```

I have also created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Raskar_gis/pen/KKdBaeB) page.

Answer (score 0):

I was running up against something similar and I realized that with the async functions the problem is the data is completely gone once the function is out of scope.

What I then realized is that the solution is just a matter of storing the data in a place it would persist longer than the scope of the function.

I resorted to localStorage.

Here is an alternate ending to your codepen that resolves the problem you are experiencing (code starts at line 109 in the codepen):

```
          dicotest[key]=input_attribute
      //console.log(dicotest)
      const data = JSON.stringify(dicotest);
        localStorage.setItem('dicotest', data);
      return JSON.stringify(data)//can actually do away with this line which means you could also not set the const data but instead just do the one JSON.stringify(dicotest)... 
        }
      })
})
    }
})
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dicotest')));
```

NOTE1: sessionStorage can be used instead of localStorage ... same syntax but will be forgotten when the users session expires

NOTE2: The first time you add the code you may not see any results because when the console.log occurs it has no data ... if you saved, or if you make a change in the HTML pane, you should see the data appear in the console.

Comment: Thank you for your time and your answer. The solution I have found is to create a HTML table in the pop up, then I can easily update the HTML table with the info from the local storage.

Comment: Glad it helped!
It actually gave me a spot to test sessionStorage and putting in and getting back out JSON data from the two storage options as well.